# multiple image upload with one form for django admin

Tags: python, django

I want to upload multiple images  with one form  i think i have somewhere problem here is my view

```
def home(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = DocumentForm(request.POST)
       files = DocumentForm(request.FILES.getlist('photo'))
       if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                 f.save() 
                 return render(request , 'core/home.html')
   else:
       form = DocumentForm()
   return render(request, 'core/home.html', {
       'form': form
   })
```

model.py :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150 )
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to= 'media')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form.py :

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('title', 'photo', )
        widgets={"photo":forms.FileInput(attrs={'id':'files','required':True,'multiple':True})}
```

Comment: But you create two `DocumentForm`s in your view?

Comment: Furthermore your model is not capable to handle this. The way you have implemented it now means that a `Document` has a `title` and a `photo`.

Comment: Okay So can  you tell little bit more about fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
files = DocumentForm(request.FILES.getlist('photo'))
```

for this

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('photo')
```

And then

```
if form.is_valid():
    for f in files:
        file_form = DocumentForm(f) # some thing arround that 
        # Or just create it as Models Document.objects.create(...) or Document(...) and Document.save()
        file_Form.save() if file_Form.is_valid() else None            
        return self.form_valid(form)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files